# Can I make direct changes in the Front-End in asp.net core 2.1 MVC, without republishing the solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, publishing, asp.net-core-2.1

The project that I am working on is created in ASP.NET Core 2.1, and I need to make simple small change on the front-end, directly on the server where the app lives. My problem here is that in the latest version of .net core, the views after publishing, are collected in one Views.dll witch is not editable. The published version on the server is a bit old and the project itself has some core changes and they are not finished yet, and I am not able to rebuild and make a new publish version of it, but due to some demo purposes client needs some simple changes on the front-end.

If anyone faced the same problem and have the solution for this, please share.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of silent issues here. First, your entire development methodology needs to change. If you're not using a version control system, you should start immediately. You can create a free Azure DevOps account (formerly VSTS) and create private remote Git repos there. Github is also an option, but only public repos are free; you need a paid account to create private repos. While there's other version control system choices, Git is by far the most used and most friendly.

Once you've employed version control, you then should follow the maxim that you don't pollute the master branch. The master branch of your repository should always contain the pristine copy of your code that could be deployed at any time. For in-progress work, you create a branch and then work on that branch. This allows you to make and commit changes without affecting the deployable copy of your code. If you were working in a branch in this case, you'd have no issue deploying a demo. You'd simply commit your work in progress to your branch, switch to master, publish, and then switch back to your branch to keep working.

When you finish whatever new functionality or changes your working on, you should then create what's called a pull request. The pull request effectively merges your code with the master branch in a preliminary way allowing an automated build to be performed on it to verify that the code in master will still compile correctly with this new code applied to it. When the build passes, the pull request can then be merged into master and the branch you were working in can be deleted. Rinse and repeat.

Now, the pull request process is a little complicated, especially if it's just you as the only developer for the codebase. You can technically just merge your branch directly into master when you're done. However, I'd encourage you to still use pull requests, and particular to combine that with automated builds, which can easily be set up in Azure DevOps as well.

Long and short, the best solution to your problem here is to ensure that it's not a problem in the first place. Having version control will do that for you, as well as providing a host of other benefits.

That said, it is possible to turn off the view precompilation, which then will allow you to modify views in place on your published app. You simply need to edit your csproj file and add the following to one of your item groups:

```
<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
```

However, this will negatively impact the performance of your web app. Additionally, modifying a live site in place is extremely bad form, and a recipe for disaster. I still *strongly* encourage you to leave view compilation in place and go the version control route.